# Reproduce LightGBM Custom Loss Function for Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

I want to reproduce the custom loss function for LightGBM. This is what I tried:

```
lgb.train(params=params, train_set=dtrain, num_boost_round=num_round, fobj=default_mse_obj)
```

With default_mse_obj being defined as:

```
residual = y_true - y_pred.get_label()
grad = -2.0*residual
hess = 2.0+(residual*0)
return grad, hess
```

However, eval metrics are different for the default "regression" objective, compared to the custom loss function defined. I would like to know, what is the default function used by LightGBM for the "regression" objective?

Answer (score 6):

as you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/7076cb8a3ac3a7b32dcf37be5593dddf27bf7f16/src/objective/regression_objective.hpp#L130-L131), this is the default loss function for regression task

```
def default_mse_obj(y_pred, dtrain):

    y_true = dtrain.get_label()

    grad = (y_pred - y_true)
    hess = np.ones(len(grad))

    return grad, hess
```