# Lightgbm scores for custom RMSE loss function and build-in RMSE are different

Tags: python, lightgbm

To start with custom objective functions for lightgbm I started to reproduce standard objective RMSE. Unfortunately, the scores are different.
My the example is based on this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-loss-functions-for-gradient-boosting-f79c1b40466d) or [github](https://github.com/manifoldai/mf-eng-public/blob/master/notebooks/custom_loss_lightgbm.ipynb).
Grad and hess are the same as in lightgbm [source](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/1c27a15e42f0076492fcc966b9dbcf9da6042823/src/objective/regression_objective.hpp#L702-L732) or as given in the answer to following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290304/reproduce-lightgbm-custom-loss-function-for-regression). 
What is wrong with the custom RMSE function? 
Remark: In this example the final loss seems to be close but the trajectory is totally different. I experience even bigger differences in final loss in other (bigger) examples.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
import lightgbm 
from sklearn.datasets import  make_friedman1
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=10000, n_features=7, noise=10.0, random_state=11)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

gbm2 = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(objective='rmse', random_state=33, early_stopping_rounds = 5, n_estimators=10000)
gbm2.fit(X_train,  y_train, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], eval_metric='rmse', verbose=10)
gbm2eval = gbm2.evals_result_

def custom_RMSE(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_pred - y_true)
    grad = residual
    hess = np.ones(len(y_true))
    return grad, hess

gbm3 = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(random_state=33, early_stopping_rounds = 5, n_estimators=10000)
gbm3.set_params(**{'objective': custom_RMSE})
gbm3.fit(X_train,  y_train, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)], eval_metric='rmse', verbose=10)
gbm3eval = gbm3.evals_result_

plt.plot(gbm2eval['valid_0']['rmse'],label='rmse')
plt.plot(gbm3eval['valid_0']['rmse'],label='custom rmse')
plt.legend()
```

eval_results for gbm2:

```
Training until validation scores don't improve for 5 rounds
[10]    valid_0's rmse: 10.214
[20]    valid_0's rmse: 10.044
[30]    valid_0's rmse: 10.0348
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[28]    valid_0's rmse: 10.028
```

eval_results for gbm3:

```
Training until validation scores don't improve for 5 rounds
[10]    valid_0's rmse: 11.5991 valid_0's l2: 134.539
[20]    valid_0's rmse: 10.2721 valid_0's l2: 105.516
[30]    valid_0's rmse: 10.0801 valid_0's l2: 101.608
[40]    valid_0's rmse: 10.0424 valid_0's l2: 100.849
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[44]    valid_0's rmse: 10.0351 valid_0's l2: 100.703
```

and here as plot:
[losses for standard RMSE and custom RMSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bEp0.png)

Answer (score 1):

RMSE is the square root of MSE (Mean squared error):

[image: MSE equation]

So, if you want to minimize RMSE you should change your function custom_RMSE() to a measure of squared residuals. Try:

```
def custom_RMSE(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_residual = (y_pred - y_true)**2
    grad = squared_residual
    hess = np.ones(len(y_true))
    return grad, hess
```

Anyway the custom_RMSE() function doens't look like to give:

> grad -> array-like of shape = [n_samples] or shape = [n_samples *
>   n_classes] (for multi-class task)
>       The value of the first order derivative (gradient) for each sample point.
>
> hess ->array-like of shape = [n_samples] or shape = [n_samples *
>   n_classes] (for multi-class task)
>       The value of the second order derivative (Hessian) for each sample point.
>   Source: 
>   https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html

Comment: To square the residuals must be wrong. Let’s use MSE instead of RMSE. I think that’s exactly what LGBM ist doing as the minimum of MSE and RMSE are the same. The paratial derivative of MSE with respect to Y_i_hat is 2*(Y_i – Y_i_hat). I guess it is usual to define MSE with factor ½ to avoid multiplication with 2 in derivative. But even if I use multiplication with 2 the trajectory is still different. My expectation is that standard MSE (RMSE) will lead to the same trajectory as custom MSE (RMSE). I am not confident with custom objective functions if I cannot reproduce the standard function.